# MLTT/MiniTT: why do normal forms of sum types carry environments?

Tags: type-theory, dependent-type, normalization

I am learning how to implement [MiniTT: a simple type theoretic language](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/%7Ebengt/papers/GKminiTT.pdf), which is a dependently typed language with sum types, mutual recursive/inductive definitions and a universe of small types.

A sum type in this language is created using `Sum(c1 A1, ..., cn An)`, which contains objects of the form `ci E : Sum(c1 A1, ..., cn An)`, where `E: Ai`. For example, booleans are encoded as `Sum(true 1, false 1)` where `1` is the unit type. The type of naturals is encoded as `rec Nat : U = Sum (zero | succ Nat)`. Sum types are eliminated using case-analysis, written as `fun(c1 M1, ..., cn Mn)`, where each constructor is `ci` and the associated handler is `Mi`. For example, the elimination rule for booleans can be encoded as:

```
Bool : U = Sum (true | false)
elimBool : Π C:Bool → U. C false → C true → Π b:Bool. C b
= λ C.λ h0.λ h1.fun (true → h1 | false → h0)
```

The evaluator for type-checking using a normalization-by-evaluation strategy, where it first converts `Exp` into `Val` (values), and then reads back `Val` into `NExp` (normal-form-read-back-expressions). This `NExp` contains for sum-type related expressions, *extra information* that was not present in the `Exp` syntax. For example, the value `NFun` (normal form of sum-type eliminator) holds on to the *entire environment*, as does `NSum` (normal form of sum type). These environments are compared when checking for equality of normal forms! The precise Haskell code is:

```
-- | Values
data Val =
  Lam Clos -- has closure
  | Fun SClos -- has sum-closure
  | Sum SClos -- has sum-closure

-- | Normal form expressions
data NExp = 
...
| NLam Int NExp -- no closure
| NFun NSClos -- holds onto closure!
| NSum NSClos -- holds onto closure!
```

1. Why does the read back versions of sum types (`NSum`) and sum eliminators (`NFun`) need to compare the entire environment, while the same is not necessary for lambda (`NExp`)?
2. Can I have a counterexample of terms that get incorrectly considered as equal if we forget their environments?

For completion, here are all the types:

````
type Branch = [(Name,Exp)]
data Rho = RNil | UpVar Rho Patt Val | UpDec Rho Decl
type SClos = (Branch, Rho)
data Clos = Cl Patt Exp Rho | ClCmp Clos Name

data NRho = NRNil | NUpVar NRho Patt NExp | NUpDec NRho Decl
type NSClos = (Branch, NRho)
```
````

Comment: Maybe it helps to also provide the definition of `SClos`